# Can I generate several uiOutput-s from the same R Shiny module?

Tags: r, module, shiny

Here is my code in R Shiny using modules.

I created a module named MyModule and want to generate two UI elements: selectInput and textInput. This code is just an example - in my real application second element require the result from the first element, so I want to generate them separately.

I don't understand why the second uiOutput doesn't generate the UI element it indended to:

---

```
 library(shiny)

    # Define UI 
    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(MyModuleUI("one")))

    # Define server logic 
    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {callModule(MyModule, 'one')})

    #Here is my UI Module 
    MyModuleUI <- function(id) {
      ns <- NS(id)
      fluidRow(
        uiOutput(ns('ChooseNumber')),
        uiOutput(ns('EnterText'))

      )
    }

    #Here is my server Module 
    MyModule <- function(input, output, session) {

      output$ChooseNumber <- renderUI({
        # In my bigger program I need this UI to be generated with some database values, 
        # thats why it is in the Server part of the Module 
        ns <- session$ns
        selectInput(ns("TheNumber"), label = 'Select a number', c(1,2,3))

      })

      # Same here 
      output$EnterText <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        textInput(ns('TheText'),label = 'Enter a text:',value = 'ABC')
      })

    }

    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of trying to render to UIs, you could put both components in `tagList`. (Assuming the inputs are to appear together)

Comment: works for me, maybe put `MyModule` and `MyModuleUI` above the `ui` and `server` assignments.